# Multiple implementation of the same method that might have differents dependencies with Go and Interfaces

Tags: go, interface

I have a problem about using interfaces.

I have a Compute(a, b int) Method that has 2 implementations, depending on the receiver.

```
func (addition *Addition) Compute(a, b int) int{
    return a+b
}

func (mult *Multiplication) Compute(a, b int) int{
    return a*b
}


type myInterface{
    Compute(a, b int) int
}
```

Let's imagine I need to call a webService in Multiplication to get the value of a.

Now we have:

```
func (mult *Multiplication) Compute(iface WSInterface, a, b int) int{
    a := iface.getA()
    return a*b
}
```

Now, I will need to add `iface WSInterface` into `Compute()` Interface definition, and add it to Addition, even if it doesn't need it.

I will end with:

```
type Addition struct{}

type Multiplication struct{}


func main() {
    addition := &Addition{}
    multiplication := &Multiplication{}
    res1 := addition.Compute(nil, 1, 2)
    res2 := addition.Compute(multiplication, 3, 4)
    fmt.Print(res1, res2)
}

type WSInterface interface {
    getA() int
}

func (mult *Multiplication) getA() int {
    return 1 // Mocked
}

type myInterface interface {
    Compute(iface myInterface, a, b int) int
}

func (addition *Addition) Compute(iface WSInterface, a, b int) int {
    return a + b
}

func (mult *Multiplication) Compute(iface WSInterface, a, b int) int {
    return iface.getA() * b
}
```

but in Addition, it will not be used.

In real life, you can have several dependencies to different microservices, and I find it not so elegant to define params that you will not use in your function. There must be something wrong here.

Is it ok to do this, is it a bad pattern, or how should I do to fix it ?

Comment: Your example is very confusing because you seem to depend on myInterface in the implementation of that same interface, and then call getA which isn't defined in the interface. Anyway, one would typically make additional, specialized parameters a field of the struct implementing the interface. Just think about the plethora of io.Reader implementations in the standard library that all have to do special things.

Comment: Yes, I made a mistake with my example! I will correct it

Comment: Made the changes, I think now it is ok !

Comment: You seem to misuse interfaces for what plain functions are good for. Instead of `Addition` and `Multiplacation` struct implementing an interface you can use plain simple first class functions in Go: Have `func Add(a,b int) int` and `func Mul(a, b int) int` and pass these to `func Compute(binaryOp func(a, b int) int, arg1, arg2 int) int`. No need for interfaces. Interfaces allows to write polymorphic functions taking various types but our Addition and Multiplication "types" have no raison d'etre at all.

Comment: You example is still totally confusing. You state "Let's imagine I need to call a webService in Multiplication to get the value of a. Now we have:
func (mult *Multiplication) Compute(iface WSInterface, a, b int) int" which makes no sense whatsoever: Either `a` is an input to Compute or determined by Compute from iface, but there is never a reason to have both.

Comment: Now you've made it so that it's clearly Compute's caller that should call getA.

Comment: An interface defines an API. If two types don't have the same API, they won't satisfy the same interface. If they don't have the same API, *an interface wouldn't be useful because they aren't interchangeable*.

Comment: Probably the best advice is to stop any "designing". Do not use interfaces. Start with concrete stuff, write things two or three times, then collect common functionality into functions. Some functions might use interface arguments. Do not try to go javaish by starting with fancy interfaces first and implementations second. In Go it works better the other way around: Start concrete, and see which interfaces _evolve_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These special interfaces/objects should be passed in the constructor, keeping the interfaces themselves clean.

Something like:

```
type Multiplication struct {
  iface otherInferface
  // .. other Multiplication-specific fields
}

func NewMultiplication(iface otherInterface) *Multiplication {
  return &Multiplication{iface: iface}
}
```

And then:

```
func (mult *Multiplication) Compute(a, b int) int{
    a := mult.iface.getA()
    return a*b
}
```

So your `myInterface` remains simple and clean:

```
type myInterface interface {
  Compute(a, b int)
}
```

Comment: I think this is exactly what I am looking for. Will implement it at the end of the week, and I will tell the results ! Thanks !